# Why does Ruby not Symbol#=~ (regex match operator)?

Tags: ruby

Ruby doesn't automatically stringify symbols when performing a regex match on them, which is easy to do when you have variables containing symbols and you forget that you need to call #to_s on them before trying a regex match:

```
>> :this =~ /./
=> false
>> :this =~ :this
=> false
>> :this =~ /:this/
=> false
```

It turns out that :=~ is defined in Object, Ruby 1.8's primordial class:

http://rubybrain.com/api/ruby-1.8.7/doc/index.html?a=M000308&name==~

Of course, the implementation just returns false, leaving it up to subclasses like String and Regexp to provide meaningful implementations.

So why doesn't Symbol provide something like the following?

```
def =~(pattern)
  self.to_s =~ pattern
end
```

Any Ruby linguists out there know?

Comment: I've written a good amount of Ruby code, and haven't ever run into the problem, so I can't say it's that easy to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know the reason why it was decided that 1.8 should behave this way, but 1.9 changed in that regard:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION #=> "1.9.2"
>> :this =~ /./ #=> 0
>> :this =~ /is/ #=> 2
```

Comment: I was hoping that would be true. :)