# Why does `Symbol#match` behave differently from `String#match` and `Regexp#match`?

Tags: ruby, regex, symbols

`String#match` and `Regexp#match` return a `MatchData` when match succeeds:

```
"".match(//) # => #<MatchData "">
//.match("") # => #<MatchData "">
//.match(:"") # => #<MatchData "">
```

But `Symbol#match` returns the match position (like `String#=~`):

```
:"".match(//) # => 0
```

Why does `Symbol#match` behave differently? Is there a use case?

Comment: Very weird decision indeed...

Comment: Nice question. At least it is mentioned in the documentation for `Symbol#match`: _Returns sym.to_s =~ obj_. So it is purpose.

Comment: Somehow related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884242/why-does-ruby-not-symbol-regex-match-operator

Comment: It seems to me the point is again the performance. `Symbol#match` is supposed to provide best performance as efficiency is the usual benefit of using Symbol. If the method were to create a string, it would involve more internal operations (creating the object in the heap, assigning a new id, etc.). Since symbols are immutable, the string representation copy would be necessary. So, just returning the index of the first match is a more efficient way of telling if a match succeeds and if yes, where.

Comment: @stribizhev while we still have `Symbol#=~`, this explanation does not sound reasonable to me.

Comment: This seems like a bug. Look at [this commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/6e0fed271c1d2e6f2b13b99d89d43e7d00e81472). `Symbol#=~` and `Symbol#match` were equivalent to the respective `String` methods before it (during 1.9 development `Symbol` was a child of `String` for a while). But the commit changed the underlying C function of both(!) to `sym_match()` (which is the impl. of `=~` and returns an integer).

Comment: @cremno Thanks for the information. I will try to file that as a bug report on Ruby core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported it as a bug in Ruby core: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11991. Let's see what they will say.

---

**Update**
The questioned behaviour seems to have been a bug. It seems that from Ruby 2.4, `Symbol#match` will return a `MatchData` instance when a match succeeds.